# zsh parameter expansion puzzle : last argument of command

Tags: zsh, parameter-expansion

I need to find the last argument of a command, check if it's a valid file name, if so I pass that to `fre` which is part of my command-completion toolchain.  The code I have works except in one case: if the last argument of the command is a valid file name containing embedded spaces.  I can't see how to deal with this.  Any ideas?  Here's the code:

```
   fre_preexec () {
      local tmpcmd="$1"
      local cand_fname="${tmpcmd##* }"
      [ -f "$cand_fname" ] && fre --add "$cand_fname"
   }
```

According to the documentation, for `preexec` `$1` contains the entire command string.
Thanks in advance.

Edit: I managed to get something that snagged a file name, but I can't get that to past the `-f` test:

```
   local tmpcmd="$1"
   local cand_fname="${tmpcmd##*[^\\] }"
   echo "cand_fname ${cand_fname}"
#   [ -f "$cand_fname" ] && fre --add "$cand_fname"
   [ -f "$cand_fname" ] && echo fre --add "$cand_fname"
```

If the command is `ls -l fred\ bill.txt`, this prints

```
cand_fname fred\ bill.txt
```

but does not `echo` anything.  I can't figure that part out.

Comment: An example command is 
```
ls -l fred\ bill.txt
```
where I want to get the `fred\ bill.txt` bit.  I actually have something that works, but it now fails the `-f` test:

```
   local tmpcmd="$1"
   local cand_fname="${tmpcmd##*[^\\] }"
   echo "cand_fname ${cand_fname}"
   [ -f "$cand_fname" ] && echo fre --add "$cand_fname"
```
The echo statement says `cand_fname fred\ bill.txt` but the `-f` test fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a mix of the `z` [parameter expansion flag](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) to split a string according to normal shell rules, and the `Q` flag to handle removing the literal backslash (And other quote related characters) left in the arguments to `preexec`. For example:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

preexec () {
    local tmpcmd="$3"
    # Note the nested expansion
    local cand_fname=${(Q)${(z)tmpcmd}[-1]}
    print "cand_fname: $cand_fname"
    [ -f "$cand_fname" ] && echo fre --add "$cand_fname"
}


ls -l fred\ bill.txt
```

and in action:

```bash
$ touch "fred bill.txt"
$ zsh demo.sh
cand_fname: fred bill.txt
fre --add fred bill.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 x x 0 Feb  7 05:07 'fred bill.txt'
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I wanted!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since `$*` contains all arguments, you could do a

```
${*: -1}
```

The space after the colon is crucial; otherwise `:-` would be parsed as a single operator.

**UPDATE**

This accesses the last command of the function we are in. The question addresses the problem, that inside `preexec`, the last argument of the command going to be executed should be displayed. I don't think that this is possible - at least not with `preexec`. The `preexec` function receives the command as a printable string. For instance, if we run a command

```
"foo bar" ${(z)$(baz)}"bam bom"
```

`preexec` would see this line as a string, but to understand that the last argument to `foo bar` is the stdout of running the command `baz` catenated to the string `bam bom`, we need first to parse the command line according to the zsh syntax (i.e. interpretation of quotes), but without actually executing `baz` know its output. Without executing `baz` we can (because of the `(z)` flag) not even know whether the whole output of `baz` will be part of the last argument.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I tried, it didn't work.  zsh's preexec has three arguments, and your suggestion gets the third argument ($3) which is "the third argument contains the full text that is being executed."

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I thought you mean the last argument of a function. AFIK, `preexec` only gets you the command string as a whole, but not in individual arguments.

Comment: According to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/zsh/comments/jmqb98/get_the_actual_name_of_command_from_preexec_hook/)  article, what you want to achieve is impossible with `preexec`. The article discusses getting the first element (not the last), but the problem seems to be the same. IMO, `preexec` is designed poorly: It would be desirable to get all arguments of the commands in the form of an array.

Comment: Thanks, see the edit, I think I'm almost there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed answer.  My cases are much much less complicated than your update, does that make it simpler?  An example command is `ls -l fred\ bill.txt` ... see my edit to the original question.

Comment: I would separate your problem into two subtasks: The first is: _given a string, what is the last element of the string?_, by defining the "last element" in a suitable way. This is easier to discuss and test than fiddling around with `preexec`. Once you have a suitable solution, you can us it inside preexec. With your example, I don't know whether there will be at most one backslash in your command, and whether the backslash always precedes a white space, respectively whether you also want to catch a case such as `ls - 'fred bill.txt'` or `ls -l "fred bill".txt`.